# Domain automatically redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns

So, I have been tasked with transferring my church's website from some minor company cms to wordpress. After creating the site and uploading it to the server (of course after removing all the old files in the httpdocs folder first), the old site is still showing up when going to http://tabernaklet.no.

The .htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried making a subdomain that points to the same folder as the root domain, and it doesn't redirect. Also I have tried to disable the DNS nameserver for the site, and still the same. The server is running Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9, and is hosted by http://dataguard.no.

What do I have to do to make the domain send users to the right page?

Comment: I feel like your nameserver is resolving the domain to the wrong IP. You said your web host is dataguard.no but your domain resolves to an IP owned by servetheworld.net.

Comment: That turns out to be true, but now I have changed it to point to the right address, and checked that it now points to dataguard, but it still shows the old site (the blue and white themed one) when i check. Any more ideas?

Comment: DNS server changes take time to propagate.  Give it a few hours.

Comment: I see the new site now :) I've posted my advice as an answer, please accept if this helped you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS server is resolving the domain to the wrong IP.  You said your web host is dataguard.no but your domain resolves to an IP owned by servetheworld.net.  Change your domain name's DNS servers to the ones provided by your web host.  Note that these changes will take a few hours to propagate.